# how to convert a raw RGB data array to a bitmap in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, camera

I am trying to convert a raw RGB24 data array into a bitmap in C#, but I am running into trouble in doing so.

This is the corresponding code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

byte[] frame;
//... code
frame = new byte[1280 * 960]; 

// code to get the frame

System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle pinnedArray =   
      GCHandle.Alloc(frame, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, 3 * width, 
        PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, pointer);

MemoryStream JPEGStream = new MemoryStream ();
bmp.Save(filepath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);**
```

I get a

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll"

with the code above.

However if i change:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, stride, 
      PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, pointer);
```

to

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width/3, height/3, stride, 
      PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, pointer);
```

I do not crash and get 3 images covering 1/3 of the total area. What I should be getting is a single image that covers the entire 1280 X 960 area space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Format24bppRgb` means one pixel takes 24 bits (3 bytes), not 1 as you pre-allocate in your sample.

Change amount of bytes allocated to account for bits-per-pixel (in bytes, if using different sizes don't forget padding):

```
frame = new byte[1280 * 960 * 3]; // 24bpp = 3 bytes
```

Comment: Thanks Alexei. I overlooked that. Now my program does not crash but I get 3  images 426 X 320 covering 1/3 of the 1280 x 960 pixels, while the remainder 2/3 is black. This is how the image looks:
http://tinypic.com/r/538ltd/5

I would like get 1 of those blocks covering the 1280 X 960 area space. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried width-1 and height-1?